# Why does double.Parse ignore the sign of zero?

Tags: c#

For example, in:

```
bool eq = (1 / double.Parse("-0.0")) == (1 / -0.0);
```

`eq` will be `false`.

`double.Parse` would have to go through some trouble to explicitly ignore the sign for zero, even though not doing that almost never results in a problem. 
Since I need the raw representation, I had to write my own parsing function which special-cases negative zero and uses `double.Parse` for everything else.

That's not a big problem, but I'm really wondering why they made the decision to ignore the sign of zero, because it seems to me that not doing so wouldn't be a bad thing.

Comment: Why would you need the sign of the zero? IEEE 754 states that `+0 == -0` after all.

Comment: How does your code example not throw a DivideByZeroException?

Comment: @Donal: because I need the raw representation in bytes, and it's different.
@FishBasketGordo: because division by zero in IEEE 754 floating point is legal and well-defined.

Comment: @Fish: That exception isn't thrown when working with floating-point types. It says so on MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Wow, really? I learn something new everyday....

Comment: This is more complicated and interesting than I originally thought, since I was thinking of both zero's sign and division by zero in the mathematical sense. This is looking like another one of those Eric Lippert questions.

Comment: I think that ultimately it's because it should parse to values that users would _normally_ use.  There is no (negative) infinity literal nor can any string representation be parsed to infinity AFAIK, you must use the appropriate constants to get the value.  The same could be said about the special value of negative zero.  It's not a value people use every day.

Comment: I think it's probably a by-product of the conversion algorithm. Looking at it in Reflector, it extracts the digits (without the decimal point), the sign and the scale, stores it in a buffer, and passes that off to a native function. I don't know what that native function does, but if it applies the sign before adjusting for scale (i.e. before converting to floating point), it would be unable to return -0. I don't think this was deliberate. I guess you could see it as a bug, but it's borderline.

Comment: I should mention that I think `-0` is reasonably useful; you can use it to divide `1.0` and get negative infinity, and you can get it when taking a limit in the right way too. It's also apparently useful when working with Celsius temperatures; the negative sign acts as a flag that says “below freezing” even if only infinitesimally so (which matters because of complex physical hysteresis-like effects). Curiously, this is an area where Java has quite a bit more sophistication; someone at Sun knew their numerical analysis properly…

Comment: It is because the CLR contains code in COMNumber::NumberBufferToDouble() that explicitly sets the result to 0 if the exponent and the mantissa are both zero, regardless of the sign.  You can't change that.

Comment: @Jeff: actually "-Infinity" parses to negative infinity, and even "NaN" parses to NaN - it seems that -0 is really the odd one out.

Comment: @Hans Passant: okay well that moves the issue to COMNumber::NumberBufferToDouble() then - why did they decide to make it ignore the sign of negative zero?

Comment: @harold: Ah thanks for bringing that to my attention.  I've certainly had no real need to use this yet.  But I still think that what I said about the literals still holds true.  When you type in the literal `0.0`, you'd expect to get the "unsigned" zero.  When you type in the the literal `-0.0`, you'd end up getting the "unsigned" zero as well since the sign is discarded by the (compiler's) parser.  I would _expect_ that the value parser would behave in the same way.

Comment: @Jeff: if it was that way it would make more sense, but the C# compiler's parser doesn't throw away the sign, the literal `-0.0` results in negative zero.

Comment: @harold: Hah, I stand corrected.  :)

Comment: `-0.0` is useful in some numerical methods to determine convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the *why* per se, but a potential solution: If you see a `-` character at the beginning, parse the rest of the string and then negate it.

Comment: Sure it works, try changing `(1 / -0.0)` to `(1 / 0.0)` - the result will be `true`
Are you thinking of NaN?

Comment: @harold: Weird, no, I thought it didn't work for infinity either. (Doesn't make sense for it to.) But yeah you're right, thanks.

Comment: +∞ isn't equal to -∞ in any modern interpretation of mathematics…

Answer (score -3):

There is the difference:

1. double.Parse("-0.0") = 0, 1/0 -> INF
2. 1/-0.0 -> -INF

But the minus operator in statement 2 doesn't mean "-0.0".